# What is the maximum number of herb tablets that can be stored in the tablet box?

Tags: resident-evil-6

You can use herbs to create herb tablets that can be stored in the herb tablet box for using to heal your character. I recently found out by mistake I can hold more than the default 6, I upped it to 10. Can I stored more than this? I am a bit cautious about just trying it in case I hit the limit and I lose any tablets as a result of this.

Also, does each character have a different limit? If so, it would be good to see numbers for all characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store up to 17 tablets at one time - the game will not allow you to add more unless you are at 11 (stored) or under.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is correct, and does appear to be the same for all characters